# What is the best component practice for creating non-ribbon visual menus on Delphi Forms?

Tags: delphi, menu, components, action

I'm am revamping some menus to tidy them visually and streamline my use of third part libraries in favour of using Delphi components where possible (I was using the very flexible DevExpress TdxBar). I want to ditch this third party use and create a menu with layout similar to the following:

[image: Example menu - similar to Delphi IDE]

After some experiment I see that I can use a TCoolBar to host (at left) a TActionMainMenuBar which provides the File..Help menu items (using action categories) and then a TCoolBand to host buttons for the stuff to the right of 'Help'.

I've no need for user rearrangement of menu items or toolbar docking. All my menu item targets are actions. My question relates to whether this is in fact the easiest way of achieving a mix of a 'main menu' with tool buttons or whether there is a better way that I'm missing. Any suggestions must relate to Delphi built in components. I already know and have used, menu components from other third party libraries.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you already have access to the DevExpress components, I'd suggest you keep using them.  They are high quality and widely used: if you want 'best practice' you can't go far wrong with a company like that. (Upgrade to the latest version.) What I'd actually suggest if you want 'best practice' is to rethink your UI design - a menu & toolbar on the same line is confusing and cluttered; the toolbars don't have drag handles; the icons are not easily interpretable, etc.  Stick with your high-quality components, and use them in a better way.

Comment: Thanks but my question states that I wish to eliminate a dependency on this library.

Comment: I know, which is why it was a comment not an answer. Why do you want to 'streamline' component usage, though, especially if you're using such good ones? But: If you really want statically positioned menus, use a classic TMainMenu. If you want toolbars without drag handles etc, use a TPanel or TToolbar and TToolButtons to go below it. Simple, plain, classic interface. If you want the toolbars on the same line as the main menu, something like you've done in your question is probably the best way.